# display online pdf in angular 6

Tags: angular, pdf, angular6, pdf-viewer

I have some pdf files uploaded in Firebase Storage.
I want to show them in my angular 6 application. I am trying with ng2-pdf-viewer but can't display online pdf.
Please suggest me the proper way to show pdf from my online stored file

HTML code:

```
<pdf-viewer 
    *ngIf="hasPdfLoaded"
    [src]="pdfSrc" 
    [render-text]="true"
    (after-load-complete) = "pdfLoaded($event)"
    [show-all]="false"
    style="display: block;">
</pdf-viewer>
```

ts file:

```
  hasPdfLoaded = false;
  pdfSrc = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/fetsl-fc873.appspot.com/o/uploads%2F_31%2FFET-317%2FReview_Thermodynamics_2.pdf?alt=media&token=a4471a81-2686-4d69-98cf-91648932b96e"

  pdfLoaded(event){
    this.hasPdfLoaded = true;
    console.log("laoding complete");
  }
```

running this code I found errors which are given below.

1. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2. ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib'

Comment: What happens when you run this code? Do you get error messages?

Comment: You can load it on iframe and the browser will render it for you with the standard command (IE: zoom, next page, scroll, etc)

Comment: It shows an error that file not found and 
"WARNING in ./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51410711/warning-in-node-modules-pdfjs-dist-build-pdf-js-module-not-found-error-cant